# Weird bug where session information is lost in Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I'm having a weird issue where I'm setting some values on my flask session. It took me a couple of tries to repeat this error, but this is how it goes down.

- I open my page in private mode and login.
- I fill my form and I submit, and I get an `Internal Server Error 500`.
- My log file wasn't capturing the error, so I made another log file capturing the values of the session (`log_file2`). With this, I could see that all of my session values disappeared (no idea how).
- I made a `log_file2` at the end of `main()` and all of my values were there, but when I enter save, none of them are there.

Now, here is the interesting part :

If I get the error, close the window, wait a while and reopen (again in private) I can replicate the error once again. But, if after I get the error I log on again, I fill my form and I submit, it works perfectly, I don't get any errors and my session values are all there. I closed the private window, reopened after a few minutes and tried submitting my form (with the same user) and it worked perfectly. I tried again but with an user I just created (new private window) and it gave me the error. The thing is, in production, the error appears once, the user retries and he can submit perfectly up until a couple of days when the error reappears once again for one time. I really am having trouble identifying what this could be. This is my first time making a flask web application so maybe I am missing something.

Any help that you can give me will be appreciated.

This is the code:

```
@app.route("/main")
def main():
    session.permanent = True

    try:
        if 'user' in session and 'client' in session and 'user_uid' in session:
            session['start_date'] = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
            session['start_time'] = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M')
            context = {
                'discipline': session['discipline']
            }
            log_file2('None necessary')
            return render_template('main.html', context=context)
        else:
            session.clear()
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    except Exception as ex:
        log_file(str(ex), 'main')


@app.route("/save", methods=['POST'])
def save():
    session.permanent = True

    log_file2(request.form.to_dict())

    form_fields = Fields.get_fields_with_attr(session['client'])
    values = request.form.to_dict()
    try:
        visit_uid = str(uuid4())
        img_data = values['sig-data']
        img = base64.b64decode(img_data)
        with open(join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), "static/img/sigs/{0}.png".format(visit_uid)), "wb") as fh:
            fh.write(img)

        if 'on-site' in values:
            values['on-site'] = 1
            values['visit-date'] = session['start_date']
            values['time-arrival'] = session['start_time']
            values['time-finish'] = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M')
        else:
            values['on-site'] = 0
            visitDate = datetime.strptime(values['visit-date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
            values['visit-date'] = visitDate.strftime('%Y%m%d')
            timeArrival = datetime.strptime(values['time-arrival'], '%I:%M %p')
            values['time-arrival'] = timeArrival.strftime('%H%M')
            timeFinish = datetime.strptime(values['time-finish'], '%I:%M %p')
            values['time-finish'] = timeFinish.strftime('%H%M')

        datetime_object = datetime.strptime(values['time-leave'], '%I:%M %p')
        time_string = datetime_object.strftime('%H%M')
        values['time-leave'] = time_string
        values['emp-num'] = session['user']

        Visit.prepare_fields(values, session['user_uid'], form_fields, visit_uid)
        session.clear()
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    except Exception as ex:
        log_file(str(ex), 'save')
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of investigating and reading, it turns out that the problem was that i was using `os.urandom(24)` for my secret key. I generated a string with that function and replaced the function for the string and it is now working perfectly.